# Why I cannot get the class when the classname(with package) which is retrieved from a HashMap is passing through Class.forName()?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a HashMap which contains several things(the content of HashMap is shown below). When I store dependencyClassName in a variable (Suppose dependencyClassName) and send that as argument in `Class.forName()`,it shows `ClassNotFoundException`.

But if I set the same classname as an argument of `Class.forName()` within a double quote, instead of getting it from the HashMap, it works fine.

I can't understand what is the problem here. I have posted the code below.

```
HashMap<String,String> dependency = (HashMap<String, String>) map.get("dependency");  //It contains ({dependencyClassName2= dao.TransactionDAO, dependencyClassName1= dao.AcountMasterDAO, dependencyType1=dao.IAcountMaster, dependencyType2=dao.ITransaction})

ArrayList<Object> className = new ArrayList<Object>();

String dependencyClassName  = dependency.get("dependencyClassName1");

try {

    System.out.println("in factory dependency: " + dependencyClassName);  //dependencyClassName = "dao.AcountMasterDAO"
    Class cls = Class.forName(dependencyClassName);//It gives ClassNotFoundException


    Class cls = Class.forName("dao.AcountMasterDAO");//It works fine    

} 

catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencyClassName1= dao.AcountMasterDAO
```

You have a leading space in the value.